# WinForms program containing a WebBrowser only works in debug mode

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, webbrowser-control

I'm creating a very simple browser in Visual Studio C#. It runs fine inside the editor, but when I run the build standalone, explorer freezes and one or more "MyBrowser.exe" process is/are running, which can't be stopped in task manager. I've narrowed the problem Down to the point that I have created a new clean Windows Forms project, dragged a WebBrowser control onto the form, build the app, and launched the exe from Windows explorer. Still freezes.

Details: I'm running Windows 7 64-bit, the newest Internet Explorer version installed on my PC is 11, I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean runs fine inside the editor? Do you mean inside visual studio? Does it freeze when you run from visual studio in Release configuration?

Comment: We've had this question asked many times before in the past two weeks.  Uninstall Avast.

Comment: Wow, it's Avasts fault?!

Dang, any suggestions of which (free) antivirus to use instead? :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Hans Passants suggestion, I found out it is Avast's fault. Adding my project folder to exceptions, has fixed the problem.

Comment: Glad you found the issue. BTW, I would recommend you ditch the WebBrowser control and use **CefSharp**, so instead of using whatever Internet Explorer is installed on the machine you use a specific version of Chrome, embedded in your application. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp

Comment: Actually I ended up using Awesomium.